# Invoke slot asynchronously without connecting to it using clear line of code

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, signals-slots, queued-connection

I have encountered quite freaky bug - `QAction::trigger` caused blocking dialog to appear, which caused my server which called `trigger` to go stuck (eg. not able to process socket signals until dialog was closed).

I figured out a workaround. I connect signal `void triggerWorkaround()` to slot `QAction::trigger` using `Qt::QueuedConnection` and I emit it:

```
QObject::connect(this, &HackClass::triggerWorkaround, targetAction_.data(), &QAction::trigger, Qt::QueuedConnection);
emit triggerWorkaround();
QObject::disconnect(this, nullptr, targetAction_.data(), nullptr);
```

But that's three lines of confusing code. Is there a non-confusing method to do this? I have found [`QMetaObject::invokeMethod`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3301778/607407), but frankly, that's 10 times more confusing than my current solution. Also, **I don't want to ever use method name as string!**

Comment: Maybe make a separate thread for the server's event loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can separate that into a function `QueuedInvoke` like this:

```
//overload for methods/slots
//the slot gets invoked in the thread where the QObject lives
template <typename Object, typename T>
void QueuedInvoke(Object* object, T (Object::* f)()){
    QObject signalSource;
    QObject::connect(&signalSource, &QObject::destroyed,
                     object, f, Qt::QueuedConnection);
}
//overload for functors
//the functor gets invoked in the thread where the contextObject lives
//or in the current thread if no contextObject is provided
template <typename Func>
void QueuedInvoke(Func&& f, QObject* contextObject = QAbstractEventDispatcher::instance()){
    QObject signalSource;
    QObject::connect(&signalSource, &QObject::destroyed, 
                     contextObject, std::forward<Func>(f), Qt::QueuedConnection);
}
```

This will leverage the `destroyed()` signal emitted from the temporary `QObject` to post a queued event into the event loop. The slot/functor is actually invoked when the event loop processes that event.

So, Instead of the 3 lines you posted, You can use the above function like this:

```
QueuedInvoke(targetAction_.data(), &QAction::trigger);
```

---

<sup>My answer is based on [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21653558/2666212) about executing a functor in a given `QThread`. You can refer to it for more details.</sup>

Comment: @TomášZato , In order to run the lambda in a specific thread, You can provide a context `QObject`.

Comment: Would it be possible to enable parameters using C++11 variadic templates?

Comment: @Silicomancer, Well, You can definitely have something like [this](https://pastebin.com/9xbM1wS2). But I think that using lambdas and capturing the variables you need there, makes the capturing method (i.e. value or reference) clearer when you are reading the code later. what do you think? You may also want to take a look at an alternative approach in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42566867/2666212).

Comment: @Silicomancer, but when using this approach, one can leverage blocking queued connections to wait for the function until it finishes executing in the other thread and possibly get its return value in the current thread, something like [this](https://gist.github.com/micjabbour/b8b3cfd1b566a041b8ad279a139e8362#file-qthreadutils-h-L26).

Comment: This answer is great, unfortunately doesn't work in Qt 4.8 (no functors in connections :( )