# Qt dialog how can I trigger accept() and reject() from function

Tags: c++, qt, qdialog

I have situation that I open `QDialog` window from the *main.cpp* file and then I wait for the `exec()` method to return based on success or fail of the `QDialog`. Like this :

```
   int main( ... ) {
    LoginDialog *loginDlg = new LoginDlg;

    if( loginDlg->exec() != Qt:;Accepted ) {
    return 0;
    }

    //check the login Info
    delete loginDlg;

    MainWindow w;
    w.show()
    return app.exec();
    }
```

From the Qt Examples (Address book) I saw I just can use the `accept()` and `reject()` slots.
The thing is that I like the window to close based on some function flow, and not ok/close buttons. 
How can I trigger those slots from function? .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As liaK pointed out you can just call the following functions from your code:

```
loginDlg->accept();
loginDlg->reject();
```

You can also call the following equivalent function using the result as a parameter:

```
loginDlg->done(QDialog::Accepted);
loginDlg->done(QDialog::Rejected);
```

PS: Note also there is no Qt::Accepted value as specified in your question.
The correct constant is QDialog::Accepted

Answer (score 4):

Just call them.. They are *normal* functions..

E.g:

`loginDlg->accept();`

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924439/in-qt-4-6-is-it-ok-to-call-slots-directly/3924480#3924480)..