# Qt - Ui access violation with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, qt

I have set a main window `QP_Qt` with a label on it named `serverStatusLabel`:

```
class NP_Qt : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    NP_Qt(QWidget *parent = 0, Qt::WFlags flags = 0);
    ~NP_Qt();
    void setServerStatusLabel(QString status);
    void setClientStatusLabel(QString status);

private:
    Ui::NP_QtClass ui;
}

void NP_Qt::setServerStatusLabel(QString status)
{
    ui.TCPServerStatusLabel->setText(status);
}
```

No error occurred during compilation. 
At runtime, When `setServerStatusLabel` is called from another class：

```
void ServerListenThread::run()
{
    if(! tcpServer.listen(QHostAddress::LocalHost, portNumber)) {
        window->setServerStatusLabel("Failed to listen on this port");
    } else {
        window->setServerStatusLabel("Listening");
    }
}
```

Error occurred:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x771115de of SP_Qt.exe: 0xC0000005 : access violation at 0xccccce2c
```

What may cause this error ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you don't access pointer in `setServerStatusLabel(QString status)`: `ui.TCPServerStatusLabel`? Try changing it to `ui->TCPServerStatusLabel`.

**Edit:**

I would also recommend you to use Qt Signal/Slot system instead of calling functions from other thread directly. Something like this:

In your thread's header file write signal definition:

```
signals:
    void changeStatus(QString newStatus);
```

In `NP_Qt` window, write slot definition in header:

```
public slots:
    void statusChanged(QString newStatus);
```

And connection in CPP file:

```
connect (myThread, SIGNAL(changeStatus(QString)),
         this, SLOT(statusChanged(QString)));
```

Finally, emit signal in your thread:

```
emit changeStatus("Hello from thread!");
```

Comment: It works fine ! I'm new to Qt so I'm not familiar with Signal/Slot system. Would you please tell me why Signal/Slot system is preferred to just calling functions directly ?

Comment: Well, I would recommend you to read [this](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html) article: it explains a lot. In short: you cannot achieve connection between separate threads without special thread-safe mechanism. Qt Signals/Slots represent this mechanism. You may also use [`QMetaObject::invokeMethod`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144240/qt-how-to-call-slot-from-custom-c-code-running-in-a-different-thread), but it is harder.

Comment: Please check the docs provided with Qt. There is a lot of info and a complete tutorial. Without it you'll do more errors like this in future.